# Reorganizing an Excel Sheet, one column into many columns

Tags: excel

I'm pretty new to stack overflow but I've been on here as a lurker before.
So I'm having trouble reorganizing this excel output. The original output is below. I've modified the output to preserve the confidentiality of the dataset and also in the interest of time as the dataset has over 10k cells, but the ideas should be clear.
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOuzM.png)

As you can see, there's a lot of duplicates and useless stuff and in general annoying bits. Basically I need to reorganize the data into column headers and repopulate the spreadsheet so that the data stays with the proper code number. The current column headers of supercatagory and subcategory are worthless. I've attached what I think would be the ideal here. [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD1lM.png)

I've tried using pivot tables and that kind of serves as a half measure but that would still require me to go through the output and copy and paste by hand for over 2 hours. I've also tried using transpose in excel and while that is good for the first part of the problem, making new column headers, but it doesn't solve the problem of repopulating the spreadsheet and keeping everything straight.

Thank you so much.

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, the below code works for me in testing with the data provided in your images. The big question of course is where the column headers in the After data came from. It appeared to come from column B of the Before data. I assumed these would be duplicated for each unique value from column A. As such, in the below code, only the first set of values is used to set the headers of the newly created sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeWithUniques()

    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Uniques As Collection
    Dim Unique As Variant
    Dim UniqueData() As Variant
    Dim FormulaColumn As Range
    Dim CriteriaColumn As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Dim ValueIndex As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim NewRow As Long
    Dim ErrorFound As Boolean

    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet '!!! This will need to be the currently active sheet housing your data

    ' If sheet is protected, exit
    If SourceSheet.ProtectContents Then
        MsgBox "Please unprotect the worksheet first.", vbExclamation, "Transpose with Uniques"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Get last row/column
    LastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = SourceSheet.Cells(1, SourceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set DataRange = SourceSheet.Range("A1", SourceSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    NewRow = 1

    ' Get unique UniqueData from column A
    UniqueData = SourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2
    Set Uniques = New Collection
    For ValueIndex = LBound(UniqueData, 1) To UBound(UniqueData, 1)
        If InCollection(Uniques, CStr(UniqueData(ValueIndex, 1))) = False Then
            Uniques.Add UniqueData(ValueIndex, 1), CStr(UniqueData(ValueIndex, 1))
        End If
    Next ValueIndex

    ' Set application properties for better code running experience
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Add helper columns
    On Error GoTo TransposeWithUniques_Error
    SourceSheet.Cells(1, LastColumn).Offset(0, 1).Resize(LastRow, 2).Insert
    Set CriteriaColumn = SourceSheet.Cells(1, LastColumn).Offset(0, 1).Resize(LastRow, 1)
    Set FormulaColumn = SourceSheet.Cells(1, LastColumn).Offset(0, 2).Resize(LastRow, 1)
    FormulaColumn(1, 1).Value = "FORMULA"
    CriteriaColumn(1, 1).Value = "CRITERIA"
    FormulaColumn(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Formula = "=ROW(A1)"
    FormulaColumn(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = FormulaColumn(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value

    ' Loop through all uniques, get data and move it
    For Each Unique In Uniques
        CriteriaColumn(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Formula = "=1/(A2=" & Chr(34) & Unique & Chr(34) & ")"
        CriteriaColumn(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value = CriteriaColumn(2, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1).Value
        DataRange.Resize(, DataRange.Columns.Count + 2).Sort Key1:=CriteriaColumn(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=SourceSheet.Range("B1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FoundRange = CriteriaColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            If TargetSheet Is Nothing Then
                Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=SourceSheet)
                TargetSheet.Range("A1").Value = SourceSheet.Range("A1").Value
                TargetSheet.Range("B1").Resize(1, FoundRange.Cells.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Intersect(SourceSheet.Range("B:B"), FoundRange.EntireRow).Value)
            End If
            NewRow = NewRow + 1
            TargetSheet.Cells(NewRow, 1).Value = Unique
            TargetSheet.Cells(NewRow, 2).Resize(1, FoundRange.Cells.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Intersect(SourceSheet.Range("C:C"), FoundRange.EntireRow).Value)
            Set FoundRange = Nothing
        End If
    Next Unique


    ' Reset data to original state
    DataRange.Resize(, DataRange.Columns.Count + 2).Sort Key1:=FormulaColumn(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    FormulaColumn.Delete xlToLeft
    CriteriaColumn.Delete xlToLeft

TransposeWithUniques_Exit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Not ErrorFound Then
        MsgBox "Process completed successfully.", vbInformation, "Transpose with Uniques"
    End If
    Exit Sub

TransposeWithUniques_Error:
    ErrorFound = True
    MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbExclamation, "Transpose with Uniques"
    GoTo TransposeWithUniques_Exit

End Sub


Public Function InCollection(CheckCollection As Collection, CheckKey As String) As Boolean
'
' Returns True if the specified key is found in the specified collection.
'
' Syntax:       InCollection(CheckCollection,CheckKey)
'
' Parameters:   CheckCollection. Collection. Required. The collection to search in.
'               CheckKey. String. Required. The string key to search in collection for.
'
    On Error Resume Next
    InCollection = CBool(Not IsEmpty(CheckCollection(CheckKey)))
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

To use the above code, in your file you want to run this on, press ALT+F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor (VBE). Press CTRL+R to show the Project Explorer (PE), generally this shows by default. Find your project in the PE and right-click it, select Insert, Module. Double click the newly inserted module (should be named **Module1**). Copy/paste the above code into this module. Click anywhere inside the top routine (for example, click on the text near the top "TransposeWithUniques" so your cursor is on that line, or just below it). Press F5 to run the routine.

**CAUTION**: Make sure you save a backup copy of your file prior to running this. It resets the data to its original state, but this is always good practice. Check the newly created sheet to ensure it's what you're looking for. If this *isn't* what you're looking for, please be as specific as possible in explaining the input versus output.

Regards,
Zack Barresse